# Jquery Change Selected Option by Value

Tags: jquery

how can i change selected option by value? Select object when loaded One selected by default I wanna set it by value.

```
<select id="county">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

```js
var $county_id = $('#county_id');
    var $city_id = $('#city_id').val();

    var $selected_county = $('#selectedCounty').val();



    $county_id.html('');

    $.get('/base/get_city_counties',{city_id:$city_id},function(res){
        res = eval('('+res+')');
        var len = res.length,i,$option = $('<option>'),$option_;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            $option_ = $option.clone(true).val(res[i][0]).html(res[i][1]);
            $county_id.append($option_);
        }
    });

    $('#county option[value=2]').attr('selected','selected');
```

fixed the code its working thx for helping. Placement was wrong I fixed.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var $county_id = $('#county_id');
    var $city_id = $('#city_id').val();
    var $selected_county = $('#selectedCounty').val();
    $county_id.html('');
    $.get('/base/get_city_counties',{city_id:$city_id},function(res){
        res = eval('('+res+')');
        var len = res.length,i,$option = $('<option>'),$option_;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            $option_ = $option.clone(true).val(res[i][0]).html(res[i][1]);
            $county_id.append($option_);
        }
        $('#county_id').val($selected_county);
    });
    $( 'textarea#jobdesc' ).ckeditor();
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

You quite simply pass the value you want to set as an argument into jQuery's `val()` method:

```js
$('#county').val('2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="county">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more alternative, which uses [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#county option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected','selected');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="county">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```